# Ant - replacing a string with a cmdline parameter passed as ${variable}

Tags: string, ant, replace

I run my ant script by passing an external parameter as `-Dversion=1.5.0.0`.
It needs to replace all occurences of `VERSION` in a file with the actual version passed in.

I'm trying to do this:

`<replace file="myfile" token="VERSION" value="${version}"/>`

Instead, I see `${version}` directly replaced within my file, instead of resolving it to 1.5.0.0.

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: did you try to [echo](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) it? this should totally work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [replacefilter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task :

```
<replace file="myfile">
 <replacefilter     token="VERSION"      property="version"/>
</replace>
```

Comment: you mean: use the replacefilter tag INSIDE the replace task.

Comment: @oers: That is correct...  adjusted the answer to include the context

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution - had to use single quotes for the value!

Like so:

`<replace file="myfile" token="VERSION" value='${version}'/>`

Comment: this can't be the reason it worked, the quotes are just part of the xml and don't have anything to do with how ant works. I suspect you did something wrong, maybe a typo on the command line....?

Comment: Dunno..I'll have to go over it again.

Answer (score -2):

you might want to remove double quotes from ${version}